# Is there a way to filter out the elements of a List by checking them against elements of an Array in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a List in Scala:

```
val hdtList = hdt.split(",").toList
hdtList.foreach(println)
Output:
    forecast_id bigint,period_year bigint,period_num bigint,period_name string,drm_org string,ledger_id bigint,currency_code string,source_system_name string,source_record_type string,gl_source_name string,gl_source_system_name string,year string,period string
```

There is an array which is obtained from a dataframe and converting its column to array as below:

```
val partition_columns   = spColsDF.select("partition_columns").collect.flatMap(x => x.getAs[String](0).split(","))
partition_columns.foreach(println)
Output:
source_system_name
period_year
```

Is there a way to filter out the elements: `source_system_name string, period_year bigint` from `hdtList` by checking them against the elements in the Array: `partition_columns` and put them into new List. 
I am confused on applying filter/map on the right collections appropriately and compare them.
Could anyone let me know how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to have both lists: the hdt elements referenced in `partition_columns`, and the hdt elements that aren't.

```
val (pc
    ,notPc) = hdtList.partition( w =>
                      partition_columns.contains(w.takeWhile(_!=' ')))
//pc: List[String] = List(period_year bigint, source_system_name string)
//notPc: List[String] = List(forecast_id bigint, period_num bigint, ... etc.
```

Comment: implemented & printed:
      println(notPc.mkString(",") + "," + pc.mkString(","))
But the output is not ordered. It shows:
forecast_id bigint,period_num bigint,period_name string,drm_org string,ledger_id bigint,currency_code string,source_record_type string,gl_source_name string,gl_source_system_name string,year string,period string,period_year bigint,source_system_name string.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it:
forecast_id bigint,period_num bigint,period_name string,drm_org string,ledger_id bigint,currency_code string,source_record_type string,gl_source_name string,gl_source_system_name string,year string,period string,source_system_name string,period_year bigint

The partition_columns need to be ordered as I am trying to ingest the data into Hive tables dynamically partitioned.
I tried to use Set,sortedSet but even they don't give me the ordered output.

Comment: The order of the input, `hdtList`, is preserved in the partitions, `pc` and `notPc`. If you need a different order, you can reorder the input before partitioning or you can reorder one or both of the partitioned results. In this case it looks like you want the 2 elements of `pc` presented in the opposite order, i.e. `pc.reverse.mkString(",")`

Comment: Yes. There is 'reverse'. I wanted to know if there is a collection in Scala which provides this functionality.

Comment: Most Scala collections have the `reverse()` method. Some that don't have it have the `reversed()` method instead, which is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, I think this is what you need:

```
val filtered = hdtList.filter { x =>
  !partition_columns.exists { col => x.startsWith(col) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need to use filter, because you need to remove elements from hdtList.

Map is a function that transform elements, there is no way to remove elements from a collection using map. If you have a List of X elements, after map execution, you have X elements, not less, not more.

```
val newList = hdtList.filter( x => partition_columns.exists(x.startsWith) )
```

Be aware that the combination filter+exists between two List is an algorithm NxM. If your Lists are big, you will have a performance problem.

One way to solve that problem is using Sets.